# entity framework - how do i know which property threw exception during save?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a bunch of entities with hundreds of fields in SQL, dozens are non nullable. I was hoping to create the entity, save and see which field its complaining about so that I can easily include this (very quick/easy to do using unit test), but the info i get back from EF does not display which field/property caused the error?  Why would this be?  I even did try/catch, output exception and no additional info about the problem :-(

```
System.Data.UpdateException : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  ----> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException : SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
   at PaymentDomain.IntegrationTests.EFTestSetup.Test() in EFTestSetup.cs: line 40
--SqlTypeException
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, ref Task task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, ref Task task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

Cool, how bout something like:  CreateDate

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DbContext.GetValidationErrors()` method to retrieve validation rules break information. [Article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.getvalidationerrors%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).